# Approximating a Continued Fraction

Tags: approximation, continued-fractions

From [a paper I was reading](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/gausslandenmonthly.pdf), If:

$$w=\frac {1}{3}\left\{ \frac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda^2}{1}+\frac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda^2}{1}+\frac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda^2}{1}+\frac {-\dfrac {11}{48}\lambda^2}{1}+\cdots\right\},$$

(which is a continued fraction) and "each numerator above is replaced by $-\dfrac{3}{16}\lambda^2$, then we obtain the approximation"

$$w \approx \frac {1}{12}\left( -2+\sqrt {4-3\lambda^2}\right).$$

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain how this step is calculated.

Comment: Appears to fit this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_quadratic_equations_with_continued_fractions#A_general_theorem

Comment: You should probably work on your technique in math notation in TeX/MathJax/etc.  I cleaned it up somewhat. The sixfold repetition of \lambda ^{2} with a space between the carat and the {2}, where \lambda^2 would suffice, is not necessarily bad style, but it's evidence that you're using one of those web-based programs to code this for you, and that would explain some other things, like the fact that you used \displaystyle when an actual display would make sense instead. When you write a+b+c+... instead of a+b+c+\cdots, then you'll see $a+b+c+\text{...}$ instead of $a+b+c+\cdots$, at least......

Comment: ....when normal TeX or LaTeX rather than MathJax is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the numerators with $\tau:=-3\lambda^2/16$ gives the continued fraction the approximation

$$3w\approx \left\{ \dfrac {\tau}{1}+\dfrac {\tau}{1}+\dfrac {\tau}{1}+\cdots\right\}=\dfrac{\tau}{1+3w}\implies (3w)^2+3w=\tau\implies 3w=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4\tau}}{2}$$ We take the positive root since $\tau=0$ should give $w=0$ and we conclude that 
$$w\approx\frac{1}{6}\left(-1+\sqrt{1-\frac{3\lambda^2}{4}}\right)=\frac{1}{12}\left(2-\sqrt{4-3\lambda^2}\right).$$